# code generating error while using gotoxy() in low level file copy program

Tags: c

Function `gotoxy`  when included in low level file copy program generates error.

Here's the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"d:\types.h"
#include"d:\stat.h"
#include"d:\fcntl.h"
#include<windows.h>

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
COORD coord;
coord.X = x;
coord.Y = y;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

main()
{
int inhandle,outhandle,bytes;
char buffer[512],source[128],target[128];
printf("enter source file location\n");
scanf("%s",source);
printf("enter target file name with location\n");
scanf("%s",target);
inhandle=(source,O_BINARY,O_RDONLY);
if(inhandle==-1)
{
printf("cannot open source file\n");
}
outhandle=(target,O_CREAT,O_BINARY|O_WRONLY,S_IWRITE);
if(outhandle==-1)
{
printf("cannot create target file");
}
 while(1)
{
bytes=read(inhandle,buffer,512);
if(bytes>1)
{
write(outhandle,buffer,bytes);
}
}
close(inhandle);
close(outhandle);
}
```

and here's the list of error generated by c-free ver5.0 compiler

```
--------------------Configuration: mingw5 - CUI Debug, Builder Type: MinGW--------------------

Compiling D:\c\test4.c...
[Error] C:\PROGRA~2\C-FREE~1\mingw\include\stdlib.h:293: error: conflicting types for '_fmode'
[Error] d:\fcntl.h:107: error: previous declaration of '_fmode' was here
[Error] C:\PROGRA~2\C-FREE~1\mingw\include\stdlib.h:293: error: conflicting types for '_fmode'
[Error] d:\fcntl.h:107: error: previous declaration of '_fmode' was here
[Warning] D:\c\test4.c:43:2: warning: no newline at end of file

Complete Compile D:\c\test4.c: 4 error(s), 1 warning(s)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I successfully compile the code?

Comment: Those error messages don't talk about your gotoxy function, and why do you have those headers outside the system include paths?

Answer (score 1):

The copy of `fcntl.h` you have in `d:\` (wtf?) doesn't match up with the rest of your system headers. Don't mix and match system headers like that.

Additionally: `gotoxy()` is a lib(n)curses function; it's not generally available on Windows. You may want to investigate [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

headers should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

Don't copy them around to make it work.

when you encounter an error please handle e.g.

```
inhandle=open(source,O_BINARY,O_RDONLY);
if(inhandle==-1) { perror("cannot open source file\n");return -1;}
outhandle=open(target,O_CREAT|O_BINARY|O_WRONLY,S_IRWXU);
if(outhandle==-1) { perror("cannot create target file"); return -1;}
```

and the while loop has no exit point.

```
while(bytes=read(inhandle,buffer,512),bytes>1) {
 if (write(outhandle,buffer,bytes) == -1) { perror("write");break; }
}
```

program couldn't possibly worked before, it wasn't the inclusion of gotoxy that broke it.